# Invalid SockJS path '/userToken/info' - required to have 3 path segments

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

I have created a new Springboot websocket app and booting it results in the following message being written to the console every two seconds.

```
Invalid SockJS path '/userToken/info' - required to have 3 path segments
Invalid SockJS path '/userToken/info' - required to have 3 path segments
Invalid SockJS path '/userToken/info' - required to have 3 path segments
```

I do not have any security dependencies in my POM, yet it appears to be a security issue?  Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This totally unclear message happens when you are connecting to the STOMP endpoint using a simple WebSocket client (without subscriptions and etc.).

Use a STOMP client, the most popular is [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/stomp.html)